# Length of document in doc2vec

Tags: machine-learning, python, gensim, similar-documents

I have 100 sentences that I want to cluster based on similarity. I've used doc2vec to vectorize the sentences into 20 dimensional vectors and applied kmeans to cluster them. I haven't got the desired results yet.

I've read that doc2vec performs well only on large datasets. I want to know if increasing the length of each data sample, would compensate for the low number of samples, and help the model train better?

For example, if my sentences are originally "making coffee", "making tea", "playing with dogs", would changing them to "making coffee requires a cup of milk and some coffee powder", "making tea requires boiling water and some tea leaves" (supplement each document with more information) help in getting better results? Would the model understand the context better?

Answer (score -1):

Increasing the sentence length might help, but not much. You can try n-grams(2 or 3) while vectorizing the data. Generally more number of sentences will help.

Comment: Can you explain why you think sentence length might not help much?

Comment: "making coffee requires a cup of milk and some coffee powder", "making tea requires boiling water and some tea leaves"  if you are adding like this it might help a bit, given you can do this way for all 100 sentences. 

But if you are adding grammar to the sentence rather than increasing context. grammar would be similar to other sentences, so it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Right. I understood your point about grammar - it doesn't add context to the sentence and wouldn't help.

Comment: I was thinking, and correct me if I'm wrong, making the sentences longer by adding more info may also worsen the performance - mostly because each document is going to be more widely different from the others ("making tea" and "making coffee" were somewhat similar, but "making tea requires green tea leaves, boiling water and a washed cup" and "making coffee requires milk, coffee powder and a washed cup" are more dissimilar than similar because the vocab in each sentence is different)

Comment: yes, exactly. i didn't get what kinda of clustering you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm vectorizing the data using doc2vec and applying kmeans clustering on the vectors. This should give me clusters of text, with each cluster containing text that's similar in meaning.

Comment: Okay I got that, what I want to know is making coffee and tea should be in same cluster or not

Comment: They could be, depending on the other data. If the others are "playing football", "practising karate", I would want "making coffee" and "making tea" to be in the same cluster. This isn't the actual data I'm working with. I just stated these examples to explain my problem in simple terms.